# Не правильно работает скрипт ''Конвертер температуры''

Tags: javascript

Задание

Создать код `JavaScript` для преобразования единиц, который по величине температуры по шкале ***Фаренгейта*** вычисляет величину температуры в градусах
 ***Цельсия*** и наоборот.

Веб-страница имеет два текстовых поля:

- температура ***по Фаренгейту***
- температура ***по Цельсию***

содержащие соответствующие числа.

Внешний вид:

> Температура по Фаренгейту
>
> Температура по Цельсию

Сигналом для начала исчисления служит изменение числа в текстовом поле.
Температура по `Фаренгейту (F)` и температура по `Цельсию (C)` связаны

> формулой  C = 5/9 * (F-32)

У меня здесь что то не так работает, не правильно переводит, кто знает в чём проблема?

```js
function f2c() {
  var c = document.getElementById('c');
  var f = document.getElementById('f');
  c.value = f.value * 10;
}

function c2f() {
  var c = document.getElementById('c');
  var f = document.getElementById('f');
  f.value = c.value / 10;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="3pt" style="">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Температура по Фаренгейту </td>
      <td><input type="text" id=f onkeyup="f2c()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Температура по Цельсию </td>
      <td><input type="text" id=c onkeyup="c2f()"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: где в Вашем коде формула `C = 5/9 * (F-32)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Честно, даже не скажу, верная ли формула, приведенная автором `C = 5/9 * (F-32)`, но я засомневался, и решил поискать в сети и нашел [тут](http://traveleu.ru/usefulInformation/temperatureConverter.htm).

Ну раз уж это учебное здание, опишу некоторые комментарии в коде, для автора и не только.

```js
const c = document.getElementById('c'),
  f = document.getElementById('f');



function getTemperature(val) {

  /* если  val === 'c' выполняется этот кусок кода  11111*/
  if (val === 'c') {

    /* а тут проверяем что значение input является  цифрой  и не пустой*/
    if (c.value !== '' && !isNaN(c.value)) {
      f.value = Number(c.value) * 1.8 + 32;
    } else {
      f.value = ''
    }
    /* если  val === 'c' выполняется этот кусок кода  11111*/

    /* если  val === 'f' выполняется этот кусок кода  22222*/
  } else if (val === 'f') {
    /* а тут проверяем что значение input является  цифрой  и не пустой*/
    if (f.value !== '' && !isNaN(f.value)) {
      c.value = (Number(f.value) - 32) / 1.8;
    } else {
      c.value = ''
    }
  }
  /* если  val === 'f' выполняется этот кусок кода  22222*/
}


c.addEventListener('input', function() {

  getTemperature('c')
})
f.addEventListener('input', function() {
  getTemperature('f')
})
```

```html
<span>Температура по Фаренгейту</span>
<input type="text" id=f>
<br/><br/><br/>
<span>Температура по Цельсию</span>
<input type="text" id=c>
```

Comment: `console.log(NaN == NaN);`

Comment: Igor, помню что NaN не равен NaN

Comment: `c.value !== NaN` - ??

Comment: строка строго сравнивается с `NaN`. Могу заранее предсказать результат сравнения в 100% случаев.

Comment: Чего то не соображу как исправить...

Comment: Черт, я же строку передаю

Comment: `!isNaN(c.value)`

Comment: @Igor, благодарю...)))

Answer (score 0):

Формула немного не правильная и округлять ещё нужно было)

```js
function f2c() {
  var c = document.getElementById('c');
  var f = document.getElementById('f');
  var n = (f.value * 9 / 5) + 32;
  c.value = n.toFixed(5);
}

function c2f() {
  var c = document.getElementById('c');
  var f = document.getElementById('f');
  var n = (c.value - 32) / 1.8;
  f.value = n.toFixed(5);
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="3pt" style="">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Температура по Фаренгейту </td>
      <td><input type="text" id=f onkeyup="f2c()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Температура по Цельсию </td>
      <td><input type="text" id=c onkeyup="c2f()"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```